# Probability that a number passing the Fermat test is prime

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, conditional-probability, primality-test

I'm studying a computer science textbook that has a section on the Fermat test as an example of a probabilistic method.

Given a number $n$, the Fermat test is stated as

1. pick a random number $a < n$.
2. If $a^n \equiv a\pmod n$, chances are good that $n$ is prime.
3. Else, $n$ is certainly not prime.

Excepting the Carmichael numbers, the book goes on to say:

> one can prove that, for any $n$, the condition does not hold for most of the integers $a < n$ unless $n$ is prime.
>
> Thus, if $n$ passes the test for some random choice of $a$, the chances are better than even that $n$ is prime. If $n$ passes the test for two random choices of a, the chances are better than 3 out of 4 that $n$ is prime.
>
> By running the test with more and more randomly chosen values of $a$ we can make the probability of error as small as we like.

While I understand that repeating the test increases the probability of $n$ being prime, I do not understand how they arrived at those numbers : *better than even* - testing once, *better than 3 out of 4* - testing twice.

---

I can see that, for a random choice of $a$, the first statement means $P(\text{passing the test}) \lt 0.5$ when $n$ is composite and equal to $1.0$ otherwise.

How do I calculate the probability that $n$ is prime, given that the test passes $x$ times?

Comment: I only know probability estimates for the strong fermat test. So, I have no idea whether it works for the weak test in the way described. Anyway, the strong test needs not much more effort. In Chris Caldwell's prime page there is a page (probable prime-how probable ?) that shows that in a case of a random number we only need one weak test with a random base to have a huge chance to have a prime.

Comment: I would modify the above test a bit : If we choose a random number $a$ with $1<a<n$, we first check whether $\gcd(a,n)=1$ holds. If not, we have found a non-trivial factor. If it holds, then we check $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$ which must hold, if $n$ is prime.

Comment: In the case, you actually want to verify numbers for primality, there are far more reliable tests (as also mentioned in the answer), but I guess this is only of theoretical interest.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. I found the page you mentioned [here](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/prp_prob.html).

Comment: For k rounds of MR (Miller Rabin, or Strong PRP), it is at most 4^(-k) (well known). For Fermat, see this prime pages link https://primes.utm.edu/notes/prp_prob.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could the confusion be coming from the textbook's informal use of the word "chance"?

Define these events:

- $A: n$ is prime
- $A^c: n$ is composite (i.e. complement of $A$)
- $T_k:$ passes $k$ tests

Then these are true statements:

- $P(T_k \mid A) = 1$
- $P(T_k \mid A^c) \le 2^{-k}$

But using the normal rules of probability, you cannot conclude $P(A \mid T_k) =$ anything at all, much less the textbook's informal claim that $P(A \mid T_k) \ge 1 - 2^{-k}$.

This is a classic case of confusing probability and [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function).  To the textbook authors' credit, they did not use the word "probability" (nor "likelihood") but instead use the word "chance".

Anyway, under the normal rules of probability, you can say nothing(?) about $P(A \mid T)$ unless you have a prior (unconditional) probability $P(A)$.  If you had a prior, you can use Bayes Rule:

$$P(A\mid T) = {P(A \cap T) \over P(T)} = {P(A \cap T) \over P(A \cap T) + P(A^c \cap T)} \approx {P(A) \over P(A) + P(A^c)2^{-k}}$$

We can see that, if the prior were $P(A) = P(A^c) = 1/2$ (akin to: "I have no idea if it will rain next Christmas so lets say it's 50-50"), then:

$$P(A \mid T) \approx {\frac12 \over \frac12 + \frac12 \times 2^{-k}} = {1 \over 1 + 2^{-k}} \approx 1 - 2^{-k}$$

However for any other prior, the above would not be true.  In particular, if $P(A) = 0$ or $1$, then $P(A \mid T) = 0$ or $1$ (which should be obvious anyway).

This also means something more practical: if you were to pick a random $1000$-digit integer (i.e. $P(A)$ is tiny), and then do a single test, and lets say your test is so poor that $P(T \mid A^c) = 1/2$ in this range of integers, then even if you pass the test, you absolutely *should not* conclude there is $1/2$ chance you picked a prime... because it is much much more probable that you picked a composite and just got a deceptive test result.  (Very similar to when a person gets a Positive disease test result when it is known the disease affects a very tiny fraction of the population...  the test result is probably a False Positive.)

So the question is: what is $P(A)$?  There is no good answer to that, because there is no (uniform) distribution over all integers.  (And if you use density, then the density of primes is $0$.)  That's why (IMHO) the textbook authors use the word "chance" and probably (pun intended) meant "likelihood".

Answer (score 2):

Suppose a number $n$ is composite, and not Carmichael. That means there is some integer $x$ coprime to $n$ with the property that $x^{n-1}\not\equiv 1\pmod n$.

Now we can split all the congruence classes coprime to $n$ in the following way.

$$\{y_1,xy_1,x^2y_1,...x^{r-1}y_1\},\{y_2,xy_2,x^2y_2,...x^{r-1}y_2\},...$$
Here each set is an equivalence class of numbers under the relation that you can get from one to the other (mod $n$) by multiplying by a power of $x$; $r$ is the multiplicative order of $x$. (Since $x$ is coprime to $n$, $x^r\equiv 1\pmod n$ for some minimum $r>0$.)

Now in each set, at most half the numbers are bases for which $n$ passes the Fermat test. This is because $(x^{k+1}y_i)^{n-1}=x^{n-1}(x^ky_i)^{n-1}\not\equiv(x^ky_i)^{n-1}\pmod n$ by definition of $x$, so of any two consecutive numbers in a set (with wraparound), at most one works.

Therefore at most half of possible bases $b$ have the property that $n$ passes the Fermat test base $b$. If you choose a random base, therefore, you have at most a $50\%$ chance of passing; if you choose two random bases, $25\%$ and so on.

Of course, this assumes you *know* $n$ is not a Carmichael number, which in general you don't. There are better tests (e.g. Soloway-Strassen) which have this property for any composite $n$.

Comment: So we actually have $1-(1/2)^n$ - chance assuming $n$ is not Carmichael ? What about the choice $a^n\equiv a$ instead of $a^{n-1}\equiv 1$ ? Is this equivalent for composite $n$ ?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry I didn't read your definition carefully! Yes, my answer would work equally well using $a^n\equiv a$. However, in practice the form of the test I describe is slightly better since in the unlikely event that you happen to pick an $a$ which has a common factor with $n$ my version will definitely show $n$ is composite whereas yours may not.

Comment: Not true, in the case of $\gcd(a,n)\ne 1$, we not only know that $n$ is composite , but we also have found a non-trivial factor. In the case of $\gcd(a,n)=1$ , it makes no difference. In other words, in the case of $\gcd(a,n)\ne 1$ , we would even waste time if we check the congruence.

Comment: @Peter You said the chance is $1-(1/2)^n$. Is $n$ here the number of times we run the test?

Comment: yes. this would be the result if we have 1/2 chance in every try. I see, "$n$" was a bad choice.

Comment: @Peter, the point is that when you take a randomly selected base $a$ you don't know whether $\gcd(a,n)>1$ or not. You could check, of course, but that wastes time whenever they don't have a common factor, which is almost always.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime My last comment : The primality test takes so much more time than checking the gcd, that the "waste" of time plays no role whatsoever. Moreover, if we do not apply trial division, there might well be a small factor, in which case the probability that $\gcd(a,n)\ne 1$ holds is relatively high.

Comment: Ok great. So this answer proves the first statement quoted from the book - *'the condition does not hold for most of the integers $a < n$ [when $n$ is composite]'*. Alas, my question was much more elementary regarding probability. I'll try to clarify.